# How I can get mobile operator name (UWP)?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I need to get information about mobile operator( if device is phone or if i got device with sim slot). I couldn't find any similar code to this:

```
textBlock1.Text = "Mobile Operator :- " + DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator.ToString();
```

which only works on Windows Phone 8.1 .

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible to retrieve such information on the UWP.
Even if you use Windows.Networking.Connections API.
Maybe in the future this will be included.